# Restrict outgoing network traffic by domain name (Linux)

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

My root goal is to be able to prevent attackers from making unauthorised outgoing connections on my server (e.g. for connect-back shells).

I can achieve this by blocking all ports for outgoing traffic using "ufw", except for the ones that the server needs to operate (i.e. DNS, HTTP, SSH and SMTP).

ufw allows me to only allow outgoing DNS connections to a static IP address (so I will configure the server to use Google DNS) and it allows me to restrict outgoing SSH destined for 127.0.0.1 (my automatic deployment script requires this with Git).

As I have learned, ufw doesn't truly allow outgoing restrictions based on domain names, which makes sense (from a performance perspective). I need to be able to do this to restrict outgoing SMTP connections to the domain of my mail server (currently just using Gmail to test) and for HTTP connections to Ubuntu servers (for system updates).

I know iptables allows you to specify rules based on domains, but they are translated on startup and not performed every time (i.e. reverse DNS). I know that is by design, for performance reasons.

So what is the solution to restrict outgoing network traffic by domain name (i.e. every outgoing connection needs to have it's destination IP address reverse DNS'd and matched against a whitelist of domain names)?

I'm thinking that if I can't get the domain-based half of the outgoing restrictions working, there isn't much point to restricting DNS and SSH by IP using ufw.

- Edit 1*
  So I have worked out how to use iptables directly to "forward" outgoing destined for a certain port (e.g. 80) to another port.

Then I realised that there would be no way of knowing what the original destination IP address was when receiving the forwarded traffic. That's when I found https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy and discovered that it (as a transparent Python proxy) interacts with the iptables interface to work out what the original destination IP address of a socket is.

I haven't got it all working just yet, but I am pretty sure this approach should work.

Comment: Do you have just one server? My recommendation would be to use a proxy of some kind. They often allow the whitelisting of specific domains.

Comment: I was looking into that, but could you go into more detail about it please. I.e. What server specifically? Would it need to be able to handle both SMTP and HTTP traffic, or do I need two separate ones? Would that route all outgoing traffic, or just traffic from programs configured to use the proxy/proxies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works on the one machine, because it relies on the transparent proxy being able to interface with `iptables` and get the original destination IP of the outgoing traffic.

Also note that this method is slightly hacky, in the sense that in order to overcome an infinite loop issue (redirecting to proxy -> redirecting to proxy -> ...), the firewall rules are applied to an operating system user group, meaning that any user not in the group is not going to get their outgoing traffic forwarded through the proxy.

Steps:

1. Create a new operating system user group called **proxy**
2. Add every operating system user (except for root!) to this new group
3. Get the *id* of the **proxy** group and remember it for later
4. Set up a transparent proxy server of some kind that can accept the protocol(s) you want to proxy and can interface with `iptables`. I used `mitmproxy` (which is Python based) and set it up to run as a root service and listen on *proxyPort*.
5. Add a rule to `iptables` to redirect all outgoing traffic destined for a certain port (e.g. http) to 127.0.0.1:*proxyPort*, like so:

   `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner proxyGID -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:proxyPort`, replacing *proxyGID* and *proxyPort* appropriately
6. Configure `iptables` or `ufw` to allow outgoing traffic to *proxyPort*, allow any port being proxied (e.g. 80) and disallow all others by default.
7. Configure your transparent proxy to drop requests however you like. To answer this question, you would configure the proxy to perform a reverse DNS on the original destination IP and check that the resulting domain is found in a pre-configured white list, otherwise the traffic should be dropped.